# Android Broadcast Receiver: RegisterService

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have built an app that changes the connected wifi network on the device. I need to register a service when the wifi has connected and unregister it ideally after the user changes activity or alternatively after a specified time.
I have tried extending the BroadcastReciever class as follows but this does not unregister the service and creates multiple instances of it.

```
public class ConnectionListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "ConnectionListener";
    private BroadcastService accessPlayerService;
    private boolean isRegistered = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();

        if (isConnected) {
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {

                accessPlayerService = new BroadcastService(context, "Welcome-Service");
                Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: Registering Service");
                if (!isRegistered){
                    accessPlayerService.registerService();
                    isRegistered = true;
                }

            } else {
                if (isRegistered) {
                    isRegistered = false;
                    accessPlayerService.unregisterService();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried registering and unRegistering in the `onResume()` and `onPause()` of the activity and it worked the fine but caused problem when the network changed or was unavailable on or in between these two methods.